# How to add different except expectations to one

Tags: python, exception

i am using Python Selenium Chromedriver and i am stuck at a problem. So i want to add different except Expectation to one line, like TimeoutExpectations and ElementClickInterceptedException to one.
My current code:

```
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "test2"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "test2")))
    except TimeoutException:
                for _ in range(1000):
                    print("Not available... trying again...")
                    driver.refresh()
                    ATC()
```

and i want this part look for example like:

```
except TimeoutException, ElementClickInterceptedException:
```

How to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch multiple exceptions in one line as following:

```
try:
    your_code_that_may_rise_exceptions
except (SpecificErrorOne, SpecificErrorTwo) as error:
    handle(error)
```

or slightly different syntax:

```
try:
    your_code_that_may_rise_exceptions
except (SpecificErrorOne, SpecificErrorTwo), e:
    handle(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by inserting the following `except` statement:

```py
except (TimeoutException, ElementClickInterceptedException):
```